# how to see pip(the package installer for Python) source code?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I want to see the pip source code?Because I want to find out how the pip install command works!

when you use command "pip intall xxx.tar.gz" or "pip install xxx", it's different.
"pip intall xxx.tar.gz" may search in the directory in your PC and untar the file,and cd in it , then run "python setup.py build->python setup.py install".
but "pip install xxx" will search xxx in "https://pypi.org/simple" by defualt, and download the target package. surely, it's all just my guess.

I need to see the source code. where can i find it? see the site-packages\pip ?

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it works.
Pip provides a way to install user-defined projects locally with the use of setup.py file. This method requires the python project to have the following file structure:

```
example_project/
├── exampleproject/      Python package with source code.
|    ├── __init__.py     Make the folder a package.
|    └── example.py      Example module.
└── README.md            README with info of the project.
Within this structure, user can add setup.py to the root of the project (i.e. example_project for above structure) with the following content:

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='example',  # Name of the package. This will be used, when the project is imported as a package.
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages(include=['exampleproject', 'exampleproject.*'])  # Pip will automatically install the dependences provided here.
)
```

After this, pip can install this custom project by running the following command, from the project root directory:

`pip install -e` .

source-[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager))

complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip)

Comment: @Clarence You're most welcome. You can tick the green tick (beside the answer) if you accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was so stupid to forget about Wikipedia and GitHub。the pypi has the source code url link and the documentation link too. the \Lib\site-packages\pip in your pc is the same as the [source code in github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/main/src/pip).